# What barge route did the Saturn S-II take from California to Florida?

Tags: apollo-program, saturn-v, transport

The first stage (S-IC) of the Saturn V rocket was produced at the [Michoud Facility](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52468/26446) in New Orleans.  Too large to be transported by railroad or airplane, it was delivered to Kennedy Space Center by barge.  The route is straightforward: sail across the Gulf of Mexico, then up the Atlantic coast of Florida.

The third stage (S-IVB) was built in California, but was small enough to be transported inside the Pregnant Guppy aircraft.

However, the second stage (S-II) was built in California (by North American Aviation in Seal Beach) *and* had to be transported by barge (because it was too large).  Considering that California and Florida are on different oceans, **what route did the S-II take to get to KSC?**  Did it pass through the Panama Canal?  A map or pictures would be desirable.

Comment: The first stage absolutely **did not** sail across the Gulf.  Those barges travelled the Intracoastal Waterway. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intracoastal_Waterway

Comment: @RonJohn A 3000 mile inland waterway that's been there more than a century, and I'm just now learning of it.  That's very cool!

Comment: @WayneConrad it's a big country... :D The ICW is only notable if you live along the coast.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The S-II stages (and actually also the S-IV and S-IVB stages before the Guppy aircraft) were transported by a converted Navy landing ship named the Point Barrow:

[image: Point Barrow]

(from: *[Stages to Saturn, chapter 10](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/ch10.htm)*)

This was an ocean-going ship that took the stages via the Panama Canal (basically the only option; rounding Cape Horn would take much longer and is more dangerous) up the Gulf of Mexico to Florida. The route via the Panama Canal was a serious risk, as closure of the canal would mean waiting or trying to round the cape, both options seriously jeopardizing the launch schedule. [NASA even at one point considered building a giant S-II-sized aircraft to mitigate this risk](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/ch10.htm).

Here is a map of how the various stages traveled over water:

[image: Map]

(from: [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/an-unexpected-journey-spacecraft-transit-the-panama-canal); [high-resolution version available](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/apollo_panama_canal_image.jpg))

[The trip took 16-days](https://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/an-unexpected-journey-spacecraft-transit-the-panama-canal).